# How to create custom font with italic or bold typeface in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I have one font that I have to use in my app, but is looks a little vaguely on small screens, so I want to make it bold.

I used this code:

```
font = FontFactory.createFromAsset(fontTextureAtlas, this, "Noteworthy.ttc", 20f, true, Color.BLUE);
```

But there's no options no make font bold, so I tried to use `FontFactory.create()`:

```
    AssetManager mgr = AssetManager.class.newInstance();
        font = FontFactory.create(fontTextureAtlas,
                Typeface.create(Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr,"Noteworthy.ttc"),Typeface.BOLD),
                20f,
                true,
                Color.BLUE);
```

But I got this:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
```

And I have no more ideas how to make this font bold. Does enyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find how to make text bold in AndEngine so I'm just created new font from existing one only with bold letters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would be possible for one reason. If the font doesn't contain the information for bold it wont be able to show on screen. How fonts work is pretty much a blank sheet of paper and contains all letters at different level of weight and styles(e.g. italic, underline and bold). This may be a weight issue you are seeing as it is not meant for android phones (maybe internet or not fully customized for phone).

Comment: This font definitely has light and bold typefaces.

Comment: Okay so it definitely has it. [Forum site about setting font styles to bold](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/z5fKtEf6wRY) and [an actual method used](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFakeBoldText%28boolean%29) .